# Product of unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, suppose $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $P$ is positive semidefinite such that $PU = VP$. Prove that $VP = PV$ and $UP = PU$.

This is what I have so far. Since $PU = VP$ then we have 
$$(PU)^*(PU) = (PV)^*(PV) \Rightarrow U^*P^2 U = P^2$$.

Comment: Please add information about the source of the question, and add your own efforts to the posl.

Comment: Please provide *context* to your question, as is explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have stated, 
$$
PU = VP \implies\\
(PU)^*(PU) = (VP)^*(VP) \implies\\
U^*P^2U = P^2
$$
Now, *by the uniqueness of positive semidefinite square roots*, we have
$$
U^*PU = P \implies PU = UP
$$
Thus, we concluded that $PU = VP \implies UP = PU$.  Similarly, we may conclude that 
$$
PU = VP \implies
PV^* = U^*P \implies V^*P = PV^* \implies PV = VP
$$
as desired.